# SQL Server 2008 R2 Data Move from One Server to Another

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have the following scenerio:-

1) Server 1 - SQL Server 2008 R2 Express - Collation SQL_Latin1_General_CS_As

2) Server 2 - SQL Server 2008 R2 Standard - Collation SQL_Latin1_General_CI_AS

I want to move the database from Server 1 to Server 2.

I tried backup and restore but does not work may be because of different collation. I also tried export but I'm getting some error. Please help me solving the issue.

Comment: Probably better asked on http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Which error are you getting when you're trying to restore backup from "Server 1" to "Server 2"?

Comment: I can restore the backups succesfully but with the old collation. I need to change the collation from CS to CI on the new restored database. I am getting error while exporting to excel. The error is saying 'Unexpected unrecoverable error'

Answer (score 0):

The way is to use ssis (dts) wizards or, if the db is small - to do db export-import with data export option with help of data exporting embedded in management studio, and finally - try to do simple detach-attach of db

There is separate Database Publishing Wizard, [available for download](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=5498)

> Overview
>
> SQL Server Database Publishing Wizard enables the deployment
> of SQL Server databases into a hosted environment on either a SQL
> Server 2000 or 2005 server. It generates a single SQL script file
> which can be used to recreate a database (both schema and data) in a
> shared hosting environment where the only connectivity to a server is
> through a web-based control panel with a script execution window. If
> supported by the hosting service provider, the Database Publishing
> Wizard can also directly upload databases to servers located at the
> shared hosting provider.
>
> Optionally, SQL Server Database Publishing Wizard can integrate
> directly into Visual Studio 2005 and/or Visual Web Developer 2005
> allowing easy publishing of databases from within the development
> environment.

Comment: Because I am moving data from express version, I do not have SSIS and export/import doing table by table. Is there anyway which can export data for whole database. I am having appx. 100 tables in one database and some of the table consist of almost 300,000 records. Thanks

Comment: yes, as I said - there is Data Publishing Wizard available for separate download, updated an answer